# Using Android ViewModel not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin

When using this code to get the devices data, it works well. But when doing any configuration change (orientation change), the loading starts again instead of delivering the already loaded data.

```
class DevicesViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    val data = DevicesLiveData()

    inner class DevicesLiveData : LiveData<List<Device>>() {
        init {
            SpecsUtils.devicesListLimit { value = it }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I followed some tutorial on Medium.

As I recall, ViewModel and LiveData is designed to survive configuration changes and lifecycle events, so the data should be loaded only once.

**Edit**

I'm aquiring the ViewModel like this

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get<DevicesViewModel>().data.observe(this, Observer {
    adapter.devices = it
})
```

Comment: Can you share code where you obtain `DevicesViewModel` and use it?

Comment: @ConstOrVar added

Comment: It looks strange. Don't see any errors in your code - surviving of view model during config change should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see a bit further deep in your code, but your code is probably not working because you're passing `this` and you should pass `this.activity` to the `ViewModelProvider`, like so:

```
myviewModel = ViewModelProvider.of(this.activity).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
myviewmodel.data({this.lifecycle}, { data -> Log.d("NEWDATA", data) }
```

Assuming that `data` is a `LiveData` object.
This should be done to every ViewModelProvider where you want to share data, for instance if you're sharing data between two different fragments that are bound to the same activity, then you should call `ViewModelProvider.of(this.activity)` on both of them